# Can I filter to only related tasks in MS Project?

Tags: ms-project

I have a large schedule, but in the `Network Diagram` view, I want to be able to filter to only show the tasks that are linked to the specific task I'm focused on. 
The filtered tasks are not necessarily on the critical path.

This would also be useful in the `Gantt Chart` view.

---

**Update**: I clarified that I want to filter my project to only show the *entire* string of predecessor and successors that go through an arbitrary task. Not just its immediate predecessors and successors, which is easily accomplished with the `Relationship Diagram` or `Task Entry` view.

The `Task Path` command is not useful because I don't want the related tasks highlighted, I want the non-related tasks hidden. The entire point is that I want to be able to suppress the information that's not interesting so I can fit more of the logic going through a particular activity on the screen (or printed page) at once.

Comment: Have you tried the macro I posted below?

Comment: Excellent macro. Seems to work well- even on MS Proect 2013. Did some test trials on it on 200+ task schedule- no problems. Well done & thank you.

Comment: Your post is a comment to the @HeyRomey's answer, but not an answer to the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12188)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12188)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Project 2013, the Task Path command in the Gantt Chart Tools Format ribbon will do exactly as you ask.

If you are not using Project 2013, you can display predecessors and successors to a selected task by showing the Relationship Diagram in the lower pane of a split screen or you can show predecessors and successors in the Task Form.

See azlav.wordpress.com/2012/09/20/task-paths-in-project-2013 for a method of filtering those tasks identified by the Task Path command.

Comment: I knew about the task form, but it only sounds like immediate predecessors and successors. The other options you mentioned sound very promising. I’m new to 2013 so didn't know of those features. Super excited to try and will update.

Comment: The Task path will show you all predecessors, driven predecessors, all successors or driven successors.  It changes the color of the bars in the Gantt chart.

Comment: I looked into it and neither of these does what I'm looking for. I've updated and clarified my question accordingly. FWIW, this is a feature in another (proprietary) program management and scheduling tool I've used in the past and was insanely useful.

Comment: I don't know if Jack Dahlgren's Trace macro may do what you want:

http://masamiki.com/docs/trace-task-dependencies.html

Comment: This may also help. 

https://azlav.wordpress.com/2012/09/20/task-paths-in-project-2013/

it builds off the Task Path highlights.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I’m looking for. Make it an answer and I’ll accept it for the benefit of others.

Comment: I added it on to the initial answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this:

https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Filter-tasks-or-resources-8abff3cf-52c1-42b5-b37c-66ec043acde1#__toc268525543

Look's quite straight forward.

Comment: I was thinking there may be a way to set up a custom filter for this, but couldn't figure out how to tell the filter which task I wanted to see the path to and from, and couldn't find any examples on the MS support pegs or via search.

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of the Trace Logic buttons in
https://sourceforge.net/projects/good-plus-fast-project-add-in/

Answer (score 0):

This mostly calls for VBA Macro -> you can recursively traverse from selected task and mark (e.g. using Flag1 field) if a task is predecessor. Then you can setup custom filter to show only fields with Flag1 (or you can filter from header, as you might be used from Excel)